# Can't delete child entity JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have JPA entities with relationship as such:

```
public class SuperParent {

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  @Builder.Default
  private Set<Parent> parents = new HashSet<>();

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "super_parent_id")
  private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public class Parent {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy= "parent" cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "super_parent_id")
    private SuperParent superParent;

}
```

```
public class Child {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "super_parent_id")
    private SuperParent superParent;
}
```

When I call `childRepository.deleteById()`, the delete operation does not delete the child entity, I'm out of ideas what is the problem.

Comment: Please include the entire code used to delete the entity.

Comment: childRepository.deleteById(childId); @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: The "right" way to delete the child entity would be to remove it from the parent collection and then save.

Comment: but that will mean i'm saving the entire object. I was trying to avoid that by just deleting the child entity. Is it not possible?

Comment: My suggestion may not trigger a query on the parent table.  Check the Hibernate logs.

Comment: you're right! it just updates the related entities affected and calls the delete. Thanks!